# VB.NET Reloading Active Docked Forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, refresh, page-refresh

I hope you can help as this little problem has been real headaches and after lengthy research I have found no viable solution.

My program uses an employee pay number to retrieve data from a database with nearly all forms being docked using WeifenLuo. When the pay number is changed, it clears the datasets with new information but we don't want the users to have to manually close all the open docked windows down - in effect each open window needs to refresh with new employee information. I have tried `.refersh()`, `.invalidate()` - which does not seem to reload the data within each combo/textbox.

After much research I tried this:

```
Private Sub tbPayNumber_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tbPayNumber.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Call Paynumber_Authentication()

            'close and re-open any active forms
            Dim table As New DataTable
            table.Columns.Add("Forms", GetType(Form))

            For Each frm As Form In MdiChildren 
                table.Rows.Add(frm)
            Next

            For i = MdiChildren.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1 
                MdiChildren(i).Close()
            Next

            For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim ResetForms = table.Rows(i)("Forms")
                ResetForms.Show(pnlDockMain, DockState.Document)
            Next

    End If

End Sub
```

If I run the code as above I get the annoying MS designed error "Cannot access a disposed object."

If I change the last part of the code to:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
      Dim ResetForms As New Form
          ResetForms = table.Rows(i)("Forms")
          ResetForms.Show(pnlDockMain, DockState.Document)
Next
```

I get the informous overload resolution error on the `ResetForms.Show` line - too many arguments.

Its worth saying that each form will get any information it needs as the form opens, which works correctly. Any help reloading each form would be appreciated as the only other way I can think of is to list every textbox on every form (over 30 forms) and give them new values individually - and manually. A lot of people talk about this problem, taking about the `.IsDisposed` method etc So I'm hoping you might find an elegant solution to this.

Thanks in advance, Shane

Comment: I have now managed to find a solution that works - its not very elegant so if you have any improvement, please post.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub tbPayNumber_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles tbPayNumber.KeyDown

If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Call Paynumber_Authentication()
    Call Load_Employee()

        'close and re-open any active forms
        Dim table As New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add("Forms", GetType(String))

    For Each frm As Form In MdiChildren 'load the name of each open form into a dataset
        table.Rows.Add(frm.Name)
    Next

    For i = MdiChildren.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1 'closes all open docked windows
        MdiChildren(i).Close()


    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1

        Select Case table.Rows(i)("Forms")
            Case "EmployeeDetails"
                Dim LoadForm As New EmployeeDetails
                EmployeeDetails.Show(pnlDockMain, DockState.Document)
            Case "HomePage"
                Dim LoadForm As New HomePage
                HomePage.Show(pnlDockMain, DockState.Document)
            Case "SOEInput"
                Dim LoadForm As New SOEInput
                SOEInput.Show(pnlDockMain, DockState.Document)
        End Select

    Next

End If

End Sub
```